# Microsoft HoloLens Menu creation

Tags: unity-game-engine, menu, augmented-reality, floating, hololens

I could need a little help with creating a menu for my HoloLens App in Unity. I want to have a Menu that always flies with the user (like the Windows Menu of the HoloLens itself). I got a menu that floats with the user (I use the SimpleTagalong and the Billboard scripts from the MixedReality Toolkit), but I still have problems with walls. The menu has always the same distance to the user that leads to the problem that the menu gets lost behind walls. Is it possible to decrease the distance depending to the users distance to a wall, just like the HoloLens Windows menu? Maybe you know an open source project that contains such a menu.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What you are looking for is called [Spacial understanding or mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spatial-mapping-in-unity). General Hint: Rather use a `SphereBasedTagelong` from the [MixedRealityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity)

Comment: Thanks I will try this out in the course of this week.